# SQL - Calculate Customer's Percentage of Total Orders by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm practicing SQL on this site: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_substring
, and am trying to calculate the % of total monthly orders by customer ID. So for example, if customer 10 had 3 orders in January, and there were 33 orders total in January, then customer 10's result in January would be 3/33 = 9.09%. I want each row to be a customer ID, and a column for each month.

Basically, I want to convert this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I can get the totals by month, but am having trouble getting the percentages.

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT d.CustomerID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 01 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 02 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 03 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 04 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 05 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS May,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 06 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 07 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 08 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 09 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 10 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 11 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 12 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS [Dec],
       SUM(NumOrders) AS Total
       FROM(
       SELECT CustomerID,
               DATEPART(mm,OrderDate) AS Month,
               COUNT(OrderID) AS NumOrders
          FROM Orders
          GROUP BY CustomerID,
                  DATEPART(mm,OrderDate)
         ) d
GROUP BY d.CustomerID
WITH ROLLUP
```

I've tried using this code like this to calculate the percentages, but am not getting it to work out.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 01 THEN NumOrders ELSE 0 END) / CAST( SUM(NumOrders) OVER (PARTITION BY Month) AS FLOAT) AS JanPct,
```

This is pretty basic in Excel, and seems like it should be in SQL too, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Create table #tmp (CustId INT, Jan int, Feb Int, March int)

    insert into #tmp VALUES
    (10,4,3,5),
    (11,3,1,7),
    (12,6,2,6),
    (13,5,4,4);

    Select * from #tmp


    select CustId,
           CEILING(CAST(Jan As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Jan) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100) As Jan,
           CEILING(CAST(Feb As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Feb) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100) As Feb,
           CEILING(CAST(March As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(March) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100) As March
     from #tmp


    drop table #tmp
```

if you want % symbol, convert to varchar and append %

Eg:

```
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CEILING(CAST(Jan As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Jan) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100))+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks Sahi. If you go to the link I posted, and put in 
SELECT * FROM Orders
you will see the original data I am working from. So I am doing some additional aggregation, using the code I posted, that makes it a little more complicated. Thoughts?

Comment: you mean, you have only order date, not month, correct? And From Orders table you want to derive th result.?

Comment: On order date: I have order date but am deriving the month with DATEPART. I'll play around with your example some more, should hopefully be able to get it to work. I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make rollup work with PIVOT, so here is the long solution.

```
DECLARE @t table(OrderId INT identity(1,1), OrderDate date, CustomerID INT)

INSERT @t values('2017-01-01', 1),('2017-01-01', 1),('2017-02-01', 1),('2017-01-01', 2)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(ROUND(count(*) over(partition by CustomerID, Month(OrderDate))*100./ count(*)
      over(partition by month(OrderDate)), 0) as INT) Pct,
    Month(OrderDate) Mon,
  CustomerID
FROM @t
)
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 1 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 2 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 3 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 4 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 5 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS May,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 6 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 7 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 8 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 9 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 10 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 11 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Mon = 12 THEN Pct ELSE 0 END) AS [Dec]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use below code instead of selecting `COUNT(OrderID) AS NumOrders` in your below subquery

```html
CONVERT(numeric(10,2), count(Orderid) * 100.0/ (select count(Orderid) from [Orders]))  as NumOrders
```